# i want to create 3D pyramid by OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to create a 3d pyramid by using only boxes.

I know that there is a function to appear pyramid but I want to try using only boxes with for loop. But I stuck with that coding. So I want to ask somebody who can help me out with this problem with the code shown.

This is my code.

```
int i = 1;
int x;

for(i=1;i<7;i++)
{
    {
        for(x=0; x<i ; x++)
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            translate(1-x+sqrt(i)+(i)+1/6,0,1/6);
            glutSolidCube(1.0);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        translate(-1, -1, 0);
    }
    rotate(rotation,0,1,0);
}
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: it will be extremly slow... you need 3 nested for loops. for example inner most loops through `x,y` would make square of size z*z  ... why rotate? translation is enough ... to speed this up you can render just the outside cubes (not rendering the inside ones)

Answer (score 0):

For a pyramid of blocks, you'll need 3 nested loops. I loop, for each dimension. The outer loops iterates through the layers of the pyramid. The size of a layer depends on the height:

```cpp
float angle = 0;

void display(void)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.1, 50);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    angle += 1.0f;

    for(int z=0; z<7; z++)
    {
        int size = 7 - z;
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                glPushMatrix();
                glTranslatef(-(float)size/2 + x, -(float)size/2 + y, (float)z);
                glutSolidCube(1.0);
                glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    }

    // [...]
```